# How can I stream using OBS to a local server which can convert the stream into a file?

Tags: networking, streaming, video-streaming

As stated above, I would like to stream to my lan server using OBS (open broadcaster software)

In OBS there is a "save to file" option but the quality can be quite low and take up a lot resources on the computer. I have a file server I use for just about everything with a decent CPU and plenty of storage space.

I'm trying to find some software which can convert the stream from my client computer to a file  on the server, so all the rendering is done on the server rather than my computer. This will free up a lot of resources on the client computer.

My client computer is running windows 8.1 and my server is running windows server 2012 r2. I am able to use Ubuntu on the server too but I would rather use windows as everything is already setup.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found this really nice tutorial on how to do this with Ubuntu.

Here's the link: http://obsproject.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=18&t=2651

All you have to do is download and compile nginx with it's RTMP module. You can then setup a simple configuration to do whatever you want, e.g: save the stream, forward it to other people, forward it to twitch etc.

I have tested stream forwarding and saving the streams to a disk and it works extremely well. The only downside is you have to compile nginx yourself but on Linux it's not really a big deal.

Comment: BUT BUT BUT why Nginx only? is there no sample on Python, PHP, Perl or BASH or Apache???

Comment: Found this, which will work on Windows as well https://helping-squad.com/obs-studio-send-an-udp-stream-to-a-second-pc-using-obs/

Comment: @user285594 the reason nginx is often recommended is based on the (from my experience at least) good and reliable RTMP module. In contrary, Apache might be able to do the same, but doesn't come AFAIK with this functionality out of the box. The nginx module is also easy to use and, by its nature of being a nginx module, very performant and backed by a configurable and mature webserver. You can though extend nginx with e.g. [perl](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/dynamic-modules/perl/) or [custom modules](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/extending/).